# Twiiter card in drupal 7 with media using meta tag, open graph and twitter card

Tags: drupal-7, twitter-card

I want to show content with images. I have seen twitter tags are form now how I can share twitter. What link I need to give. Even its validated by twitter validator tool.

Here are the tags formed

```
<meta property="twitter:url" content="xyz.com/blog/blogpage">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="acbc">
<meta property="og:description" content="xyz">
<meta name="keywords" content="abcd">
<meta name="description" content="xzcczxcczxc">
<meta about="blog/blogpage" property="acx:num_replies" 
content="0" datatype="xsd:integer">
<meta content="ABCD" about="/blog/blogpage" property="dc:title">
<meta property="og:image" content="xyz.com/sites/default/files/field/image/image.jpg">
<meta property="twitter:creator" content="@abc">
<meta property="og:title" content="zyz">
<meta property="twitter:image:height" content="500">
<meta property="twitter:image:width" content="500">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. validate url that I need to share along with media using twitter card validator. 
   .
2. passed url to twiiter share link.